# Django - Most efficent display of list values (ForeignKey or ChoiceField)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am designing a `Django` model, but found myself using many `ForeignKey` relations, and consequently started to have slow loading times (specially inside the Admin panel).

However most of these `ForeignKey` relations are just to display a `name` field.

```
class Field1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Field2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Field3(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

...


class Main(models.Model):
    ...
    field1 = models.ForeignKey(Field1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field2 = models.ForeignKey(Field2, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field3 = models.ForeignKey(Field3, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I could change these fields to `ChoiceField` but I would hard-code the choices inside `models.py` (not ideal)

I imagine it would be possible to do something like this, but would it be faster/more efficient?:

```
class Fields(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class ListValues(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey('Fields', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)    

class Main(models.Model):
    ...
    field1 = models.CharField(choices=ListValues.objects.get(type__name='Field1'), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field2 = models.CharField(choices=ListValues.objects.get(type__name='Field2'), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field3 = models.CharField(choices=ListValues.objects.get(type__name='Field3'), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Any insights would be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: In your admin class you can list the foreign key fields under `raw_id_fields` to for faster page loading.

Comment: @bdoubleu yes, I am aware of that.

Comment: Your issue is just that you have a lot of objects for each foreign key so the page is taking a long time to render all the choices?

Comment: Do you have something like [django debug toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to debug the cause of the slow loading time

Comment: @IainShelvington yes, but using `raw_id_fields` the page loads faster. What I am trying to understand is what would be the best/fastest way to still have the dropdown option in each field.

Comment: The `__str__` method for each related model just returns the name?

Answer (score 0):

The [select2](https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package can provide you with select inputs that will not render all options on page load, they provide a search like widget that perform AJAX requests to get matching options.

Specifically the [ModelSelect2Widget](https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django_select2.html#django_select2.forms.ModelSelect2Widget) should do what you need

```
class NameSearchWidget(ModelSelect2Widget):
    search_fields = [
        'name__icontains',
    ]

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('field1', 'field1', 'field1')
        widgets = {
            'field1': NameSearchWidget,
            'field2': NameSearchWidget,
            'field3': NameSearchWidget,
        }
```